Why are the x86 registers ordered A, C, D, B?
I figure there must be a practical reason, maybe something regarding the optimization of hardware, but I am curious for a definitive answer. When a ModR/M byte references a registry, it is done in the following way:
(In r8 mode)
r=0b000 for AL
r=0b001 for CL
r=0b010 for DL
r=0b011 for BL
r=0b100 for AH
r=0b101 for CH
r=0b110 for DH
r=0b111 for BH

The pattern follows for r16 and r32.
Why is this? Why not order them A, B, C, D?

This is answer in Retrocomputing.SE Why are first four x86 General Purpose Registers named in such unintuitive order?
